# Send email Outlook 2013 as a background process

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a small macro to send an email every Friday to about 20 people from different departments at the office.
The way I did this was to have a spreadsheet with a name and an email associated to it, and then looping through it changing the appropriate info. I want the email to go to each person, so no, the other recipients are not supposed to be CC'd or BCC'd.

It works. However, to avoid problems, I put a pause so each email goes out every 6 seconds, in blocks of 10, with a pause of about 10 secs between blocks. I believe that pause is creating lag, and while the job is completed, I cannot use Outlook (to check other emails, or Tasks).

Is there a way to have Outlook send each email in some sort of "silent-mode"?

Here, code:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub PrepareEmail()
.
.'A bunch of variable and simple data manipulation is done here.
.
For emailLooper = 0 To BrokerForm.LstBoxBrokers.ListCount - 1
Set oMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mySMTPserver"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "username"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    .Update
End With

With oMail

Set .Configuration = iConf
.Subject = asunto
.HTMLBody = emailText & signatureEmail

    destName = BrokerForm.LstBoxBrokers.List(emailLooper, 0)
    emailAddress = BrokerForm.LstBoxBrokers.List(emailLooper, 1)

    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "#name#", destName)
    .To = emailAddress
    .From = senderEmail
    .Send

    emailsSent = emailsSent + 1

    Sleep (6000)

    If emailLooper / 10 = Fix(emailLooper / 10) Then

        Sleep (11000)

    End If

End With


Set oMail = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing

Next emailLooper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `Sleep()` API function, you can try creating a loop timer with the `DoEvents` function.

Try seeing if this helps:

```
Dim startTimer as single, sleepTime as single
sleepTime = 6

With oMail

Set .Configuration = iConf
.Subject = asunto
.HTMLBody = emailText & signatureEmail

    destName = BrokerForm.LstBoxBrokers.List(emailLooper, 0)
    emailAddress = BrokerForm.LstBoxBrokers.List(emailLooper, 1)

    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "#name#", destName)
    .To = emailAddress
    .From = senderEmail
    .Send

    emailsSent = emailsSent + 1

    startTimer = Timer
    Do While Timer < startTimer + sleepTime
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If emailLooper / 10 = Fix(emailLooper / 10) Then

        startTimer = Timer
        Do While Timer < startTimer + sleepTime
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End If

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As K.Dᴀᴠɪs mentioned, You could use Loop instead of using Sleep().

Outlook will locks you out until sleep period has finished if you use `Sleep()`. You can use `CTRL+BREAK` to interrupt the macro, but Outlook won't accept input from the keyboard or mouse.

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[Pausing or Delaying VBA Using Wait, Sleep or A Loop](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop)